# How do I make basic authentication available to my controller in asp.net web api .net 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-6.0, basic-authentication

I have implemented a user validation class and a Basic Authentication Attribute class that verifies the token present in the header of a request by decoding and converting it. Next, the validation class checks the provided username and password. A GET request fails to prevent access to the data even if no username or password is provided.

I tried adding "[BasicAuthentication]" to a controller.

```
namespace minimalAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [BasicAuthentication]
```

I've also tried to make the authentication available to the entire application but didn't work either.

```
namespace minimalAPI
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to look at [idunno.Authentication.Basic](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/blob/dev/src/idunno.Authentication.Basic/README.md) which is also available [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/idunno.Authentication.Basic). It allows you to properly set up an authentiation scheme for basic authentication with your application.

Comment: Thank you so do you think the main reason its not working is because of how I set up my BasicAuthenticationAttribute class? @poke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller. Here is good [example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/12/20/net-6-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) to implement basic authentication in .NET 6 Web API

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be getting a 401 unauthorized now. A combination of what @poke suggested and this did the trick.